# Paired values within arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have been given an array to store within it different currencies.
array[usd=1.57, eur=1.24]
how do I make it so that I can type usd and the value stores is 1.57 or eur is 1.24
first I need to store these values into the array from a csv file

Comment: `$foo = ['usd'=>1.57,'eur'=>1.24]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$curr = array('usd'=>1.57, 'eur'=>1.24);
echo $curr['usd']; // 1.57;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are called Associative Arrays

```
$curr_values = array('usd'=>1.57, 'eur'=>1.24);
echo $curr_values['usd']; // 1.57;

// you can store individual values like this

$curr_values['usd'] = 1.57;
$curr_values['eur'] = 1.24;
```